# What is the correct way to represent the intersection of two non-null events?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I would like to define a set for two sets $A$ and $B$ such that:

$$
\{x: \{x \in A\} \neq \emptyset \ \ \cap \ \ \{x \in B\}\neq \emptyset \}
$$

That is, I would like find the collection of events $x$ that are simultaneously not the empty set under both $A$ and $B$. Is there a more elegant way to write this?

Comment: What does "not the empty set *under* both A and B" mean?

Comment: What does it mean for an event $x$ to "be the empty set under $A$" where $A$ is a set? The notation $\{x \in A\}$ is not clear to me.

Comment: @user657324 But the $x$ in $\{x : x \in A\}$ is a [dummy variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable)), since $\{x : x \in A\} = \{y : y \in A\}$. Even more simply, $\{x : x \in A\}$ is just the set $A$...